# CUDA FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: when using 'import cudf' WSL2, Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, wsl-2, rapids, cudf

I am attempting to run cudf in a Jupyter Notebook in a conda rapids23.12 environment. I painstakingly went through all the steps to install the necessary drivers and packages, however when I run 'import cudf', I get:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/robfes/anaconda3/envs/rapids-23.12/nvvm/lib64'

Cannot find a fix for this.

Running Nvidia Geforce RTX 3070 which should be compatible.

I've tried editing the .bashrc file by adding
"LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/robfes/anaconda3/envs/rapids-23.12/nvvm/lib64" but that has not worked.

Searching my computer for that folder and it was not found. So my question is how do I get this file installed and why was it not installed when I installed rapids

Comment: Can you include the output of `conda list`?

Can you add more information about how you installed CUDA? On WSL2 you only need CUDA drivers on the host Windows OS (don't install drivers in the WSL system). Conda should be able to provide the CUDA runtime, and `conda list` will help explain that.